# Does a xamarin.android app have su permissions when deployed to a rooted device

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, rooted-device

My HTC One (M8) phone is rooted and is running Android 6.0. The Root Check app verifies that the phone in rooted ok.

I have developed an Xamarin Android app in c# and the following permissions are included in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
```

When I deploy my Xamarin Android App through Visual Studio 2017 several strange things happen which seem to be permission related...

1. The app is re-installed each time - all files are removed and re-added
2. Images saved to the external directory (sd card) via camera only have rw------ permissions
3. Copying files in code from sd card to app local folder return empty file

So my question is does a xamarin.android app have su permissions when deployed to a rooted device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACCESS_SUPERUSER` permission DEPRECATED since Android 5.0. [Due to changes in Android 5.0 Lollipop, this permission has been deprecated and is completely ignored from SuperSU v2.30 onwards](http://su.chainfire.eu/#updates-permission).

> The app is re-installed each time - all files are removed and re-added

This issue may related to the location where your files are placed, for example, all files created in the data/data/your.app.package is deleted automatically upon install. And if you saved files that are app-private(by calling `getExternalFilesDir()`), when the user uninstalls your application, this directory and all its contents will be deleted. Please read the official document: [Using the External Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

> Images saved to the external directory (sd card) via camera only have rw------ permissions
>
> Copying files in code from sd card to app local folder return empty file

It is possible that you only defined `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, if you want to read from external storage, please add the following permission too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```